# I tried POST in Google Form it Error Code 401 In Python

Tags: python, post, request, google-forms

I'm a newbie and I tried POST in Google Form it Error Code 401
what should i do please ?

```
import requests

url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdKZSc0lddatSdr4xZfLIvrXsAp5_pvJmtCdGGVjJFSjll29A/formResponse'

payload = {
    'entry.927608146':'Name',
    'entry.284890744':'Lastname',
    'entry.1635320286':'Tel',
    'entry.508926427':'BKK'
}

r = requests.post(url,payload)
```

My form link : (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdKZSc0lddatSdr4xZfLIvrXsAp5_pvJmtCdGGVjJFSjll29A/viewform)

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to submit data via Google form.